# node.js benchmark not smooth

Tags: node.js, benchmarking, node.js-connect

I write a simple page like this

```
var connect = require('connect');

connect.createServer(
  connect.router(function(app){
    app.get('/no-db', function(req, res, next){
       res.end(JSON.stringify({/* object here*/}));
    });
  })
).listen(3000);
```

when I run

```
ab -c 100 -n 10000 http://127.0.0.1:3000/no-db
```

it process the request, sometimes fast, sometimes slow, sometimes just stopped, very unstable.

what does this mean? I am using Mac OS X lion.

Answer (score 0):

it could be garbage collection, you should check if you memory req is going up very fast then falling very fast. If it does you are creating a lot of objects.

Comment: are there any optimization tips for GC?

Answer (score 0):

**There is a bug in `ab` on Mac OS X Lion (7.3.x)**

This is not an issue with Node.js

Basically, install a patched version of `ab`

You can reference the similar problem [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2664)

A patching guide is here [here](http://forrst.com/posts/Fixing_ApacheBench_bug_on_Mac_OS_X_Lion-wku)

This frustrated me to no end! Good luck :-)